# a better way to view the field name and values in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

In my form I have got fields which are setup like below:

```
<div>
    Email
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="lead[email]">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
     First name
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="lead[name]">
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on. When user fills all the fields then I need to generate a confirmation view, in this case it is simply a separate tab in the same page. 
This is how I am showing the fields which have been filled.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr ng-show="user.name" >
     <td class="col-md-4">Name:</td>
     <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="user.email" >
    <td class="col-md-4">Email:</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think there should be a better way to collect the all and run a loop to show all the field name and their field value.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all object properties with values using `ngRepeat` like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in user">
        <td class="field-name col-md-4">{{key}}:</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/XiA63e74xpm9aVNUdXCM?p=preview

Also note, that I used `.field-name {text-transform: capitalize;}` in CSS to capitalize key name for better readability so that `email` appears as `Email`.